# Argument of type 'Request' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpRequest<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new. Please be gentle and speak layman.

In the following typescript code, I'm getting this error in my method sendRequest()...

**Argument of type 'Request' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpRequest'. Property 'body' is missing in type 'Request'.**

---

I attached an image of the message. Anyone know how to fix this please? No luck on google.

```
import { Movie } from "./movie.model";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestMethod, Request, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Filter } from "./configClasses.repository";
import { Studio } from "./studio.model";

const studiosUrl = "/api/studios";
const moviesUrl = "/api/movies";

@Injectable()
export class Repository {
    private filterObject = new Filter();
    private movieData: Movie;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        //this.filter.category = "drama";
        this.filter.related = true;
        this.getMovies(true);
    }

    getMovie(id: number) {
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, moviesUrl + "/" + id)
            .subscribe(response => { this.movie = response.json(); });
        //console.log("Movie Data Requested");
    }

    getMovies(related = false) {
        let url = moviesUrl + "?related=" + this.filter.related;
        if (this.filter.category) {
            url += "&category=" + this.filter.category;
        }
        if (this.filter.search) {
            url += "&search=" + this.filter.search;
        }
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, url)
            .subscribe(response => this.movies = response);
    }

    getStudios() {
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, studiosUrl)
            .subscribe(response => this.studios = response);
    }
    createMovie(mov: Movie) {
        let data = {
            name: mov.name, category: mov.category,
            description: mov.description, price: mov.price,
            studio: mov.studio ? mov.studio.studioId : 0
        };
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, moviesUrl, data)
            .subscribe(response => {
                mov.movieId = response;
                this.movies.push(mov);
            });
    }
    createMovieAndStudio(mov: Movie, stu: Studio) {
        let data = {
            name: stu.name, city: stu.city, state: stu.state
        };
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, studiosUrl, data)
            .subscribe(response => {
                stu.studioId = response;
                mov.studio = stu;
                this.studios.push(stu);
                if (mov != null) {
                    this.createMovie(mov);
                }
            });
    }

    replaceMovie(mov: Movie) {
        let data = {
            name: mov.name, category: mov.category,
            description: mov.description, price: mov.price,
            studio: mov.studio ? mov.studio.studioId : 0
        };
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Put, moviesUrl + "/" + mov.movieId, data)
            .subscribe(response => this.getMovies());
    }
    replaceStudio(stu: Studio) {
        let data = {
            name: stu.name, city: stu.city, state: stu.state
        };
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Put,
            studiosUrl + "/" + stu.studioId, data)
            .subscribe(response => this.getMovies());
    }

    private sendRequest(verb: RequestMethod, url: string,
        data?: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.request(new Request({
            method: verb, 
            url: url, 
            body: data
        })).map(response => {
            return response.headers.get("Content-Length") != "0"
                ? response.json() : null;
        });
    }

    updateMovie(id: number, changes: Map<string, any>) {
        let patch = [];
        changes.forEach((value, key) =>
            patch.push({ op: "replace", path: key, value: value }));
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Patch, moviesUrl + "/" + id, patch)
            .subscribe(response => this.getMovies());
    }

    movie: Movie;
    movies: Movie[];
    studios: Studio[] = [];

    get filter(): Filter {
        return this.filterObject;
    }

    deleteMovie(id: number) {
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Delete, moviesUrl + "/" + id)
            .subscribe(response => this.getMovies());
    }
    deleteStudio(id: number) {
        this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Delete, studiosUrl + "/" + id)
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.getMovies();
                this.getStudios();
            });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You may not be passing data in `post` req OR may be passing empty data in `get` req

Comment: Try this -> this.http.request(new Request(verb.toString(),url,{ body: data })). Also check the overloads of http.request methods. You will find it in client.d.ts. The problem with this is your Verb is of type RequestMethod, but the input needed is either "GET"/"POST" like this. You are using httpclient in combination with http RequestMethod. So in your sendRequest you need to introduce an option to convert RequestMethod.GET => "GET". Please let me know if it helps

Comment: I'm confused. Is there a way to do this without 'RequestMethod?'. I just need it to work so I don't mind another approach that's not going to be deprecated soon.

Comment: Yes ofcourse. @Vancho has mentioned the approach you can have 2 methods Get and Post, and instead of calling http.request, you can directly call http.get or http.post. (where => http : HttpClient)

Answer (score 0):

Below should work :

```
private sendRequest(verb: RequestMethod, url: string,
    data?: any): Observable<Request> {
    return this.http.request(new Request({
        method: verb, 
        url: url, 
        body: data
    })).map(response => {
        return response.headers.get("Content-Length") != "0"
            ? response.json() : null;
    });
}
```

Comment: Error is still there after changing 'any' to 'Request' :(

Comment: Yes this wont help, as the request parameter that your are passing is of type HTTPRequest (if you see in client.d.ts), which would compulsorily need more parameters like headers, withcredentials etc... SO its better to use different overload of http.request, please check my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Use "Http" in '@angular/http' like this (THIS WAY IS DEPRECATED)

import { RequestMethod, Http, Request, Response } from '@angular/http';

NOT import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Change in constructor to be:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    //this.filter.category = "drama";
    this.filter.related = true;
    this.getMovies(true);
}
```

source: [Angular.io -> api -> http -> Request](https://angular.io/api/http/Request)

OR NOT DEPRECATED YOU CAN DO LIKE THIS:

... constructor(private http: HttpClient) ...

```
  public get<T>(url: string, headers: object) {
    return this.http.get<T>(url, headers);
  }


  public post<T>(url: string, body: any, headers: object) {
    return this.http.post<T>(url, body, headers);
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the deprecated approach. I had it working like that before but trying to be current.

Comment: for get request: private sendRequest<T>(verb: RequestMethod, url: string,
        data?: any): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get<T>(url, {});
    }

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of solving this either to have get and post method specific to it like mentioned above by Vancho else, for you to get going try below code:

```
private sendRequest(verb: RequestMethod, url: string,
    data?: any): Observable<any> {

    let method: string;

    switch (verb) {
        case RequestMethod.Get:
            method = "GET";
            break;
        case RequestMethod.Post:
            method = "POST";
            break;
    }

    return this.http.request(method, url, { body: data }).map(response => {
        return response.headers.get("Content-Length") != "0"
            ? response.json() : null;
    });
}
```

I won't suggest you to go via this route, as its not scalable, you should have code specific to get/post/delet method, so for that you can have 2-3 methods:

sendGetRequest and sendPostRequest which will have http.get and http.post respectively.